# LESS - use nth-child variable in string

Tags: less, css-selectors

Surely there's a way to rewrite the following in LESS?

```
#bg-slider{

li:nth-child(1){
    background:url('../images/bg1.jpg');
}

li:nth-child(2){
    background:url('../images/bg2.jpg');
}

li:nth-child(3){
    background:url('../images/bg3.jpg');
}

}
```

I've tried:

```
.bg-image (@slide) {
  background:url('../images/bg@{slide}.jpg');
}

#bg-slider{
li:nth-child(n){
    .bg-image(n);
}
}
```

But that just gives '../images/bgn.jpg' for all li's.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
#bg-slider {
    li {
        .bkg(1);
        .bkg(2);
        .bkg(3);
    }

    .bkg(@i) {
        &:nth-child(@{i}) {
            background: url('../images/bg@{i}.jpg');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: seven-phases-max's answer is complete. But if you are like me and was looking for something more generic, this might help: `.applyToCol(@colNum...:nth-child(0n+@{colNum})`