# LESS : How to implement variable to input field with data- attribute

Tags: less

I’m new with LESS and I cannot figure out how to apply variable to input field with specific data- attribute. This is my problem:

I have multiple input fields

```
<input type=“text” data-value=“white” />
<input type=“text” data-value=“yellow” />
<input type=“text” data-value=“red” />
```

and each input field has a backround image according to data-value attribute, like this:

```
input[data-value=“white”]{
    background-image: url(“../images/white.svg”);
}
input[data-value=“yellow”]{
    background-image: url(“../images/yellow.svg”);
}
input[data-value=“red”]{
    background-image: url(“../images/red.svg”);
}
```

How can I shortend this with LESS?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through array of variable names in Less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440789/loop-through-array-of-variable-names-in-less)

Comment: Thus the proper duplicates would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492261, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626408, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954762, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369614 and so on.

Comment: Weirdly enough "Loop through array of variable names" seems to be quite popular topic when it comes to these kind of things despite the fact it's a *wrong* solution. Instead of looping through *names of variables* one usually needs to loop through just *values*. – seven-phases-max 23 mins ago

Answer (score -1):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440789/loop-through-array-of-variable-names-in-less) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256412/concatenate-strings-in-less) for some hints on solving this. One issue is that you cannot just use `attr()` within `url()`, so you need another approach which includes loops. You need to define all possible values for `data-value` before.

```
@colors: "green", "red", "blue";

.-(@i: length(@colors)) when (@i > 0) {
    @name: extract(@colors, @i);
    input[data-value="@{name}"] {
        background-image:url("../images/@{name}.svg");
    }
    .-((@i - 1));
} .-;
```